# How to I check if a spreadsheet with specific name exist in Google Sheet?

Tags: android

I am working on Android application, which shall create Google Sheet programmatically.
All is working well - I can create the sheet, write values, etc.

I cannot, however, find a way to check if another spreadsheet already exists with the same name. How to I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, instead of using the Google Sheets service, you will need to use the Google Drive service.
Here is the documentation for [searching Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files). You can filter the search by document `name`, as well as `mimeType`. It looks like a [Google Sheets document has a `mimeType` of `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)